# Tortoise SVN copy repository to new network drive

Tags: svn

We are trying to move all our projects over to a new network drive from an old server and have been using Tortoise SVN for version control

Id like to move the repository over to the new drive and keep all past logs and versions of software

What would be the best way to go about this? I have researched for a decent definitive answer but am coming up short

Comment: repositories or working copies?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the repository will keep past logs.

Options

1. Copy the repositories across to the new drive, tell everyone to relocate their working copies so that when they check it in, svn will find a repository.
2. Create a VM and do the same as 1.  The advantage is that if you then decide that the machine is getting a bit long in the tooth, just move the VM across to the new machine.  Don't use the VM for anything else.

Try it on one project and test it out - if you feel confident, then apply it to the rest of the system.